# ANY with ALL in Entity Framework evaluates locally

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-core-2.2

I have the following Entity Framework 2.0 query:

```
var user = context.Users.AsNoTracking()
  .Include(x => x.UserSkills).ThenInclude(x => x.Skill)
  .Include(x => x.UserSkills).ThenInclude(x => x.SkillLevel)
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);

var userSkills = user.UserSkills.Select(z => new { 
  SkillId = z.SkillId, 
  SkillLevelId = z.SkillLevelId 
}).ToList()
```

Then I tried the following query:

```
var lessons = _context.Lessons.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y => 
     userSkills.Any(z => y.SkillId == z.SkillId && y.SkillLevelId <= z.SkillLevelId)))
  .ToList();
```

This query evaluates locally and I get the message:

```
The LINQ expression 'where (([y].SkillId == [z].SkillId) AndAlso ([y].SkillLevelId <= [z].SkillLevelId))' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'.
```

I tried to solve it using userSkills instead of user.UserSkills but no luck.

Is there a way to run this query on the server?

Comment: What if you leave off `ToList` on `userSkills`? I don't think a local `List.Any` is translated to SQL by EF Core or EF. Another possibility is to split the test, using `Contains` to verify `y.SkillID` is in `userSkills` and do the `skillLevelId` test later.

Comment: The EF Core extension [MemoryJoin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFrameworkCore.MemoryJoin) may also be used.

Comment: @NetImage I removed the ToList and still evaluates in memory. Not sure I understand your suggestion of using Contains. Can give me an example?

Comment: I added an answer showing what I meant. Also, the ultimate answer may be to translate the `Any` to an or predicate (a || b || c ...) using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) to build the predicate depending on how many `userSkills` there are.

Answer (score 3):

You should try limiting the usage of in-memory collections inside LINQ to Entities queries to basically `Contains` on primitive value collection, which currently is the only server translatable construct.

Since `Contains` is not applicable here, you should not use the memory collection, but the corresponding server side subquery:

```
var userSkills = context.UserSkills
    .Where(x => x.UserId == userId);

var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y =>
     userSkills.Any(z => y.SkillId == z.SkillId && y.SkillLevelId <= z.SkillLevelId)))
  .ToList();
```

or even embed the first subquery into the main query:

```
var lessons = context.Lessons.AsNoTracking()
  .Where(x => x.LessonSkills.All(y =>
     context.UserSkills.Any(z => z.UserId == userId && y.SkillId == z.SkillId && y.SkillLevelId <= z.SkillLevelId)))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: @NetMage This is not primitive value collection and the criteria is not just equality, so `Contains` doesn't apply. In this case limiting means "don't use". Both presented solutions fully evaluate server side.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Contains` on the server then filter further on the client:

```
var userSkillIds = userSkills.Select(s => s.SkillId).ToList();

var lessons = _context.Lessons.AsNoTracking()
                              .Where(lsn => lsn.LessonSkills.All(lsnskill => userSkillIds.Contains(lsnskill.SkillId)))
                              .AsEnumerable() // depending on EF Core translation, may not be needed
                              .Where(lsn => lsn.LessonSkills.All(lsnskill => userSkills.Any(uskill => uskill.SkillId == lsnskill.SkillId && lsnskill.SkillLevelId <= uskill.SkillLevelId)))
                              .ToList();
```